How to type tilde (~) in Spanish keyboard in Terminal
I type option+ñ and get a ~ on most applications:
when I am in Terminal, I get (arg: 1) on bash, and ? on zsh.
The results are the same for left and right option keys.
Hardware: MacBook Pro, 15 inch, 2018
Mac OSX: Ventura 13.6.6
Keyboard: native keyboard of Macbook Pro (Spanish keyboard)
How can I get a tilde (~) on terminal on a Spanish keyboard?
I have already checked the other question that is supposed to be a duplicate of my question, in fact that solution (option+ñ) does not solve my problem.

I am using ES SPANISH on keyboard layout, not Latin America or Spanish Legacy.

On bash, pushing ñ key gives  (arg: 1)  on terminal.
On zsh, pushing ñ key gives    ñ on terminal.

locale is empty
Setting LANG=es_ES.utf-8, option+ñ gives:
-- ?     on bash
-- <ffffffff> on zsh

In  Terminal -> Settings.. -> Profiles -> Basic (or other) -> Advanced -> International I checked both:
Set locale environment variables at startup
and
Unicode East Asian Ambiguous characters are wide
and I get now ? or ±, depending on the chosen Western encoding

When you press option - is it on the left or right side of the keyboard? Also note that a space or / may be required

@bmike I have tried both option on the left and the right and it is the same. Can you give me some hint about / or space? I have tried adding them somewhere, but I cannot find a working combination

Can you edit in the version of macOS (which number and or build) and let’s reopen this for answer. Let’s edit in also that your results are the same for left and right option key and clarify - is the keyboard USB or Bluetooth or part of a portable MacBook ?

~ is normally made via option ñ then space on the Spanish layout, but option ñ on the layout called Latin American.  Which one are you using?

What is the output from locale? The C locale has very limited character handling and might produce the symptoms you're seeing. You can change the locale with export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8; export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8 (locale -a will list some other possible values).

@Gairfowl locale is empty and changing LANG does not solve the problem, as in the edited question

@TomGewecke ES Spanish

Empty output from the locale command seems very unusual - I haven't found a setting that makes that happen on my system. If you're using Terminal, you may want to try changing options in Terminal -> Settings.. -> Profiles -> Basic (or other) -> Advanced -> International, see if those have any effect.

@Gairfowl I have checked both options: when I press option+ñ , I now get either ? or ±

Well, I'm out of guesses :).  Obviously the LC_ALL and LANG variables have an effect, as do the settings in Terminal, but I have no idea if any combination of those might have the desired result.
